# can I display multiple values (like price & volume) on crosshair in jfreechart XYPlot

Tags: jfreechart

I'd like to have a way to set a string value that could format both price and volume that I display on a chart, instead of having

```
yCrosshair.setValue( (double)y );
```

or

```
myXYplot.setRangeCrosshairValue( (double)y );
```

My example shows that I plot both price and volume and have prices on the left axis and volumes on the right axis, but the crosshair on mouseMove is showing only price due to the limited function of .setValue(), and I'm not able to coax CrosshairLabelGenerator or set...LabelGenerator() to get a call to generateLabel(...).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

ah, I can use "CrosshairLabelGenerator" to create my own string-format label, but i still need to call .setValue() from chartMouseMoved() event handler to trigger the call to StandardCrosshairLabelGenerator::generateLabel()